# Python Selenium Mocking - Dictionary stub inside a mock crashes test with AttributeError why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mocking, pytest

I have an issue where I have a dictionary stub inside a mock and my test crashes. Shouldn't the mock replace everything to begin with so I shouldn't even run into this issue?

script.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

def nothing_here_really_just_setting_up_the_logic_flow():
   """
   This function is completely irrelevant. It just loads a website
   returns the webdriver session as "driver" and a dictionary 
   "add extra xpath" with the addtional xpath syntax for the function
   where my issue is at
   """     

    # Load a website
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(#some website)

    # Prepare extra xpath syntax
    add_extra_xpath = {}
    add_extra_xpath['add me'] = 1 # The actual dict is more complex then this and 
                                  # this number keeps changing so that's why I'm using a 
                                  # dict, if you're wondering

    return driver, add_extra_xpath


def function_where_I_have_a_problem(driver, add_extra_xpath):
    """
    Simply find an element on the site via a connotated xpath
    """

    # Find an element by xpath with the help of "add_extra_path"
    find = driver.find_element_by_xpath('begin writing xpath' + str(add_extra_xpath['add me']) + 'finish off the xpath')
```

test_script.py

```
import pytest
import script

from unittest.mock import MagicMock

# Mock the "driver" and stub the "add_extra_xpath" dictionary
@pytest.fixture
def fixture():

    driver = MagicMock()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath.side_effect = driver

    add_extra_xpath = {}
    add_extra_xpath['add me'] = 1

    return driver, add_extra_xpath

def test_function_where_I_have_a_problem(fixture):

    driver, add_extra_xpath = fixture

    script.function_where_I_have_a_problem(driver, add_extra_xpath)

    assert driver.call_count == 1
```

Running the test crashes due to an:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

at

```
find = driver.find_element_by_xpath('begin writing xpath' + str(add_extra_xpath['add me']) + 'finish off the xpath')
```

Shouldn't the side_effect I set back in my fixture override this 'find_element_by_xpath'?

Comment: Can you post the full error trace? I'm wondering on what line the error is thrown.

Comment: @killian95 Thanks for mentioning that! I totally forgot about that part so I'll add it in. As a matter of fact, I realized I made a few mistakes in my code. I've editted it to reflect and replicate my issue now. I can't exactly post the full error trace since this is just a simple, made up replication of the actual code. However, it does replicate the actual issue I'm having; which is a crash due to an AttributeError.

Comment: Got it. Well honestly I can't recreate the error you're getting from what you've posted -- there must be some difference between the 'example' code and your actual code. Is there any reason you can't post your real code?

Comment: I can but I'm just simplifying it down because the rest of the code is irrelevant and long. In either case, isolating the actual code further seems to pass for some reason. So my answer is lingering somewhere but I'll uncover it eventually on my own now. Whether you realize it or not, you just asking your questions just pretty much answered my question. Lolz Thanks!!!

Comment: Happy to help! I get it -- sometimes you just need to bounce it off someone to find whats wrong ;-)